# Testing middleware functions

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a test for a similar middleware module below. I am using mocha & chai, and I am stuck on how to actually call the `doSomething` function from the test file. Any suggestions on how to do it?

middleware.js

```
module.exports = function(){
    var middleware = {};

    middleware.doSomething= function(temp) {
        return temp;
    }

    return middleware;
};
```

test.js

```
var foo = require('./middleware');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
describe('middleware test', function() {
    it('doSomething test', function(done) {
        //call the doSomething function
    });
});
```

Comment: you export a function object, so If you need the return value, you need to make function call `var foo = require('./middleware')();` then foo will hold `{doSomething: function (temp) { ....}};` and you will able to make `doSomething` call in the test

Comment: Thank you! This should work.